# Solution to Txn front-running?

Tags: transactions, frontrunning

My transactions are getting front-run frequently; what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into dark pools. Transactions aren't visible in the public mempools

Heres an example of a dark pool: https://www.sfox.com/darkpool

also check out the Kraken dark pool